# Passing a parameter to perl with -p

Tags: regex, perl

I have a short perl script that runs regex replace over files:
`perl -pi -e 's/x/y/' <file>`
I want to pass a parameter to the script, so it'll replace y with the command line argument (eg, something like `perl -pi -e 's/x/$argv[1]/' <file>` but I using $argv[1] doesn't work when the -pi parameter is used.

Comment: Note that `-pi` is really `-p` and `-i`, two different options that are stacked together.  Why do you say that `$argv[1]` "doesn't work"?  What exactly doesn't work?  Can you show us actual code rather than a paraphrase?

Comment: how about set bash variables and use them in your one-line perl? like this: `Pattern='foo' && (echo 'foo' |  perl -pe 's/'"$Pattern"'/bar/')`

Comment: @qqibrow, That fails if `$Pattern` contains a `/`.

Comment: @AndyLester, $argv[1] is an empty string when -pi is used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never understood the preoccupation with one-line Perl programs, and I don't understand why you can't write a Perl script file to do this.

However, you can remove an item from `@ARGV` and save it in a variable before the `-p` loop starts. Like this

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ $r = pop } s/x/$r/' <file> <replacement>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1: Roll out your own loop.

```
perl -i -e'$r = shift; while (<>) { s/x/$r/; print }' "$replacement" "$file"
```

Solution 2: Grab the var at compile time.

```
perl -i -pe'BEGIN { $r = shift; } s/x/$r/' "$replacement" "$file"
```

Solution 3: Use an env var instead of an argument

```
R="$replacement" perl -i -pe's/x/$ENV{R}/' "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl -pi -e 's/x/y/' <file>` is equivalent to this:

```
while (<>) {
   s/x/y/;
} 
continue {
   print or die "-p failed: $!\n";
}
```

This will pass every line of `<file>` through the expression `s/x/y/;` and print the result. (Note the -i flag will modify `<file>` inplace). If you really need to pass in a replacement, why don't you list it directly in the substitution. Either way it is still listed only once.

```
perl -pi -e 's/x/<replacement>/;' <file>
```

Comment: "If you really need to pass in a replacement, why don't you list it directly in the substitution." I'm guessing the OP is invoking this one-liner in a shell script and wants to pass a shell variable. I can't imagine why else they would avoid using the replacement string directly. Of course, that's just a guess.

Comment: Couldn't you just interpolate the shell variable directly into the command? e.g. `perl -pi -e "s/x/$var/" <file>`

Comment: You could that too. Anyway, this seems like an XY problem.